# Collapsing Toolbar Title Disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-menu, android-design-library

I'm on design support library 23.0.1, and I'm using a Collapsing Toolbar Layout with parallax image. I don't understand why when the Toolbar is totally collapsed (pinned) if a click on an action button (specifically I refresh its image), the **title disappear**. After that if I drop down the header to total expansion and reclick the action button the title returns.

**ACTIVITY LAYOUT**

```
<!-- App bar -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <!-- Collapsing toolbar layout -->
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <!-- Image Parallax -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            edo:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <!-- Toolbar -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            edo:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- Nested scroll view -->
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    edo:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**ACTION MENU LAYOUT**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_bookmark"
    android:icon="@mipmap/bookmark_empty_white"
    android:title="@string/add_news_to_bookmarks"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

**OPTIONS SELECTED**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (news != null) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_bookmark:
                if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(activity)) {
                    if (news.getBookmarked()) {
                        bookmarked = false;
                        item.setIcon(R.mipmap.bookmark_empty_white);
                        deleteBookmark();
                    } else {
                        bookmarked = true;
                        item.setIcon(R.mipmap.bookmark_white);
                        postBookmark();
                    }
                } else {
                    handleError(Config.API_ERR_CONNECTION);
                }

                return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I'm with the exact same problem in exactly, when i click in my search and return back my title disappeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug seems to be fixed with [support library v23.1.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html) .

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug at Android's side. They are aware of it and looks likely to be fixed in a future release: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183333

Workarounds are posted in the link but none have been able to fix my issue.

EDIT: issue has been fixed with [Support Library v23.1.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had this weird [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183778)

And removing the attribute `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from 
just the `AppBarLayout` kind of worked for me. Can you try the same ?

Comment: Attaching a sample [repo](https://github.com/vishrayne/DisappearingTitleDemo/tree/fix_disappearing_title), just take a look